# off centered semi circle area integral

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

When I do $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$ where $f(x)=\sqrt{1-(x-4)^2}$ or any other off center semi circle function, I get the result in the form of a complex number. What does that mean? I have usually thought of integral of a function as the area between that function and the $x$-axis. The result seems to confuse me as what does complex area mean.

Comment: In your example when $x=0$ the integrand is $\sqrt{-3}.$ That isn't a real number so your integral would be interpreted as over complex numbers. Varying conventions apply to squareroots in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I now see where I went wrong and what coffeemath meant in a precise way.

Comment: Note that your cirlce is centered in $(4,0)$ with radius $1$  so the domain of the semicircle is $3≤x≤5$  while your limits of integration implies that $0≤x≤1$. To be real-valued you should change the limits of integration to something between $3$ and $5$.